# Ionic 3, ngx-translate 9.x; build -> ngc: Internal error: unknown identifier TranslateLoader & TranslatePipe

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, angular2-aot, ngx-translate

I have some difficulties with **ngx-translate (v9) with lazy-loading** under ionic 3.9.2. Everything works fine in browser until I run the "buid --prod". The npc part (i think it's the AOT compilation) of the build process reports an "unknown identifier" for TranslateLoader and TranslatePipe.

Although I have followed the [ngx tutorial by ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/), read through the github of ngx-translate and StackOverflow, I haven't found a discussion to a similar problem. Thus I would like to turn for help.

I am getting the following error when I run **ionic cordova build ios --prod** (please note the first line, shows issues with TranslateLoader and TranslatePipe):

```
Error: Internal error: unknown identifier [{"filePath":"..../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/core.d.ts","name":"TranslateLoader","members":[]},{"filePath":"..../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/core.d.ts","name":"TranslatePipe","members":[]}]
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31063:23)
    at tokenExpr (..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20063:39)
    at providerDef (..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19966:20)
    at ..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20188:77
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at NgModuleCompiler.compile (..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20188:44)
    at AotCompiler._compileModule (..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30956:32)
    at ..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30838:66
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler._compileImplFile (..../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30838:19)
[11:14:07]  copy finished in 9.27 s
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
...

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: [TranslateLoader],
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
      preloadModules: true, 
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,

  ],
  providers: [SplashScreen, Keyboard, StatusBar, {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, AuthService]
})

...
```

package.json:

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1", // 3rd version gives the same error.
```

I am then importing ngx-translate in the application as .forChild({...}) with the same exported function HttpLoaderFactory().

The weirdest thing is that when I change the initiation from

```
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
```

to (provide TranslateLoader as array)

```
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: [TranslateLoader],
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
```

The error message gets shorter to and the problem with TranslatePipe disappears:

```
Error: Internal error: unknown identifier [{"filePath":".../node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/core.d.ts","name":"TranslateLoader","members":[]}]
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31063:23)
    at tokenExpr (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20063:39)
    at providerDef (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19966:20)
    at .../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20188:77
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at NgModuleCompiler.compile (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20188:44)
    at AotCompiler._compileModule (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30956:32)
    at .../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30838:66
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler._compileImplFile (.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:30838:19)
```

Could you please help?

Best regards

Jakub

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I was initiating the TranslateModule with this in all of my pages and components:

```
TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: [TranslateLoader],
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
```

I changed it to this:

```
TranslateModule.forChild()
```

and it's working.

Maybe this will help to somebody.

Comment: I had to add this loader forChild({...}) back to the pages where I change a language, otherwise, the translations were not updating. It's passing the build process.